# Index from related object backward foreignKey relation in Django (related_name)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to index into and access the attributes from a related object referenced in another table's foreignkey:

```
class table1 (models.Model):
    name =  models.CharField()
    ....
class table2 (models.Model):
    attr1 = models.ForeignKey(table1, related_name = "backTable")
    importantAttribute = models.Charfield()
```

I'd like to access importantAttribute from table2 from the Python API interpreter:

```
 >>> t1 = table1.objects.create(name="t1")
 >>> a1 = table2.objects.create(name="a1", attr1 = t1)
 >>> t1.backTable.all() 
 >>> [<table2: a1>]
 >>>> I'd like to access importantAttribute of table2 from t1 here. how?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreignKey field creates a many-to-one relationship, so the `t1.backTable.all()` will return a list of table2 objects.

To access the related important attribute, you can just use dot-notation on the objects in the list, such as:

```
t1.backTable.all()[0].importantAttribute
```

Note that because `.all()` is returning a list of objects, you have to either loop through the list or pick out one like the example above.

In a template it could look like:

```
{% for backTable in t1.backTable.all %}
    {{ backTable.importantAttribute }}
{% endfor %}
```